# Find what percent of a line a point makes up

Tags: python, geometry, line

I have two points, x2 and x1.  I have their corresponding y's, y2 and y1.

I always know that x2>.95>x1 and that y2>y1.

so i wrote this code, in the hopes that I can basically find where along y1-y2 that .95 occurs, however I am not sure towards its accurancy, so any suggestions or notices would be nice:

```
  3 x1 = float(raw_input('x1: '))
  4 x2 = float(raw_input('x2: '))
  5 y1 = float(raw_input('y1: '))
  6 y2 = float(raw_input('y2: '))
  7 
  8 z = 0.95
  9 
 10 dist = x2-x1
 11 
 12 yi = ((1-(.01*(dist/(dist-(x2-z)))))*(y2-y1))+y1
```

please let me know if this is right, because I am not sure it is, but I am also not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of a line is `y = mx + c` where `m` is the slope, and `c` is the intercept.

Given `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, you can find `m` and `c`:

```
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
c = y2 - m * x2
```

Now that you know those, you can find the value of `y` when `x = 0.95`, by:

```
y = m * 0.95 + c
```

Comment: Thank you very much, simple geometry is always the hardest for me to remember!

Answer (score 2):

The equation of a line by two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) is `(y-y1)/(y2-y1) = (x-x1)/(x2-x1)`.
if `xi = 0.95`, then `yi = (y2-y1)*(xi-x1)/(x2-x1)+y1`